# why array.sort not work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have array of object .I want if i add object in array it should add in sorted way .I used array to sort .but it not sort my array . here is my code

https://jsfiddle.net/8oczc5x5/

```
var arr = [{
  elem: {
    text: function() {
      return "aa";
    }
  }
}, {
  elem: {
    text: function() {
      return "yy";
    }
  }
}];
var obj = {
  elem: {
    text: function() {
      return "bb";
    }
  }
}
arr.push(obj);
arr.sort()
console.log(arr[1].elem.text())
```

**Expected Out put**

```
"bb"
```

Actual output

```
"yy"
```

..why ? I used sort it should sort my array ?

Comment: Javascript can't sort array of object because, by default, the set of objects is not ordonned.

Comment: If you try with only number ( 1 , 2 , 3), it work fine.

Comment: ok so how we sort this array

Comment: You're trying to sort the array by the _results_ of functions called on inner children of objects in the array? You're going to need to write a custom sort function for that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @Hamms, is good. the syntax is `arr.sort([fonctionComparaison])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) only really works "out-of-the-box" when sorting character data alphabetically. And why would you expect it to call your functions and compare them? That's really dangerous and complicated. However, you can perform your own special sort by passing it a function.

Taken from the docs (`compareFunction` is the function you're passing in):

> If `compareFunction` is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are two elements being compared, then:
>
> If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b, i.e. a comes first.
>
> If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
>
> If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.
> `compareFunction(a, b)` must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  // localeCompare does a string comparison that returns -1, 0, or 1
  return a.elem.text().localeCompare(b.elem.text());
});
```

Comment: `s/localCompare/localeCompare`

Comment: @user944513 Why? You can literally drop this in place of your current `arr.sort()` call.

Comment: *"sort only really works "out-of-the-box" when sorting numbers and characters"* - No, it only works "out-of-the-box" on character data. It won't sort numbers numerically, you have to provide a comparitor function for that.

Comment: Thanks for the localeCompare suggestion.  This helped my coffeescript compiled javascript work correctly when return a - b was misbehaving.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify how to sort

```
arr.sort( (a,b) => a.elem.text().localeCompare(b.elem.text() );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sortNumber(num1,num2) {return num1 - num2;} var numbs = [5, 17, 29, 48, 4, 21]; 
var sortnumb = numbs.sort(sortNumber);
alert(sortnumb)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @WhatsThePoint the point (in contrast) is that even though there was no explanation, it was useful to me in solving my problem.  Programmers too can understand ugly code, not just machines.  However, I agree that explanation helps.